# Few questions about the overflow

Tags: solidity

Sorry for (maybe redundant) question, but:
If I have a payable function, and I use msg.value, like this:

```
function f() payable {
    // do something with msg.value
}
```

Should I check `msg.value` for overflow? And if yes, how can overflow happen?
For example, if I do `f1(0 - 1)`, it can go off the limit, but `msg` is composed by Ethereum network, and it should correspond to a real amount transfered, correct?

Answer (score 1):

> but msg is composed by Ethereum network, and it should correspond to a real amount transfered, correct?

That is right. There is no tampering with msg. value. However, you could of course do 1 - msg.value or things like that - msg.value is just a regular unsigned integer representing the value transfered in the transaction.